# Bootstrap 3 Overlay caption not aligned properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a pintrest style grid in `bootstrap` and in that i want to display overlay caption text on top right corner and on bottom side

But as you can see in the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9dz3xxe9/) here that my top right corner label is not aligned properly and same for bottom text as well

Even when i write text in multiline it doesnt fit in well. I want the miltiline text to be display like this below image

[image]

Also wants to fit the grid according to image,right now it gives some extra width after the image width.

So what `css` property should i adjust here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CSS

```
.row {
    -moz-column-width: 18em;
    -webkit-column-width: 18em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap:1em;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.well {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}
.well span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding:1%;
    color: #fff;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
.well h4 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding:1%;
    color: #fff;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

For a full width, cover image on each item, add `width:100%` to the `<img/>` elements.

```
.well img {
    width:100%;
}
```

**Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9dz3xxe9/1/**

Comment: it works fine but if i remove the `width:100%` than it leaves a big padding before next block. What should i do to remove that padding and keep the block side by side?

Comment: Well you can keep `width:100%` on `item` and make your images inside responsive to fit the div or you can try this plugin http://masonry.desandro.com/. I don't think there is easy solution to what you want to do but i might be wrong.